# Finding Absolute Value In Verilog Data Designated by System C/Xilinx X

Tags: fpga, verilog, xilinx, microblaze

I have been trying to find the Absolute value of an integer which is designated to Verilog core using Xilinx C running on Microblaze, what i have seen is that Verilog treats the negative number as a positive number.

I have tried all data types : `signed int`, `int`, `Xuint32`.

My c code is:

```
signed int data,value;
data=-20;value=0;
putfsl(data,0);
getfsl(value,0);
signed int data1,value1;
data=20;value=0;
putfsl(data1,0);
getfsl(value1,0);
```

After getting the values of variables I printed them on Hyperterminal.

On my Verilog side the code was:

```
out <=(in<0)?-in:in;
```

I also tried this code but results were similar

```
if(in<0)
   out=-in;
else 
   out=in;
```

Kindly help me out!

I have also tried other data types and changed parameters but results have not worked out to be I always get the same number I input i.e

```
in<0
```

statement is not being true, I also tried in<=0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I'm not a Verilogger - its signed arithmetic foibles being one of the reasons why not :)

Prior to Verilog-2001 all vector arithmetic in Verilog was unsigned.

In Verilog-2001 you can explicitly call for signed arithmetic, so I think you'll need to cast your `in`:

```
if ($signed(in) < 0)
 out = -$signed(in);
else
 out = in;
```

Reading matter which may be of interest:

[Signed arithmetic in Verilog-2001 - Opportunities and Hazards](http://www.uccs.edu/~gtumbush/published_papers/Tumbush%20DVCon%2005.pdf)